# How can I decrypt text in kotlin, encrypted in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, kotlin, encryption

I am trying to decrypt a text which is encrypted using nodejs. Simply Saying I am trying to encrypt data from the server-side and decrypt it to the client-side whenever an API gets called.

Here is my code on the server-side.

```
function encrpt(text) {
    const seckey = '12345678123456781234567812345678';

    var aesDec = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-ecb", seckey , '');
    var output = aesDec.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');
    output += aesDec.final('hex');

    return output;
}
```

This is the code in am using to decrypt on client-side it is in Kotlin.

```
fun String.test() {
    val skc = SecretKeySpec("12345678123456781234567812345678".toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), "AES")

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skc)
    val result = cipher.doFinal(this.toByteArray())

    println(result.toString())
}
```

But doing so I am getting `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT` in android studio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use like that:

```
init{
   cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
   secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(secret.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8),"AES")
    }


fun decrypt(cipheredText: String?): String? {

            val array: ByteArray = Base64.decode(cipheredText, Base64.DEFAULT)
            val encrypted: ByteArray = array.copyOfRange(0, array.size)
            cipher!!.init(
                Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,
                secretKeySpec,
                IvParameterSpec(iv.toByteArray())
            )
            return String(cipher!!.doFinal(encrypted)).trim()
        }
```

Note: iv must be 16 byte (128 bit)

Comment: What libraries do I need to import in order to use this code?